# Filter a nested array and dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, realm

I am trying to filter the array which consist of array and dictionary inside it. I want to filter based on the type of the service and then whose  isPrimaryMailbox is Yes under attributes array. 
This is what I have done:-

```
let services = Manager.realm().objects(Service.self).filter("type = %@", "MAILBOX")

let serviceWithPrimaryEmail = services.filter({$0.attributes.first?.value == "Yes"})
```

But this is showing the data which has isPrimaryMailbox value is No

Below is the json response :-

```
{
  "data": {
    "cust": [
      {
        "customerId": "2040349110",
        "serv": [
          {
            "bill": "2010007656959",
            "services": [
              {
"type": "MOBILE",
                "status": "ACTIVE",
                "plan": {
                  "name": "Mobil"
                },
                "addOns": [
                  {
                    "status": "Active"
                  }
                ],
                "hardware": [
                  {
                    "type": "HANDSET"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "MOBILE",
                "plan": {
                  "name": "Mobile Service"
                },
                "addOns": [
                  {
                    "status": "Active"
                  }
                ],
                "hardware": [
                  {
                    "type": "HANDSET",
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "MAILBOX",
                "plan": {
                  "name": "Service"
                },
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "mailboxSize",
                    "value": "1 GB"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "isPrimaryMailbox",
                    "value": "Yes"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "MAILBOX",
                "status": "ACTIVE",
                "plan": {
                  "name": "Service"
                },
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "mailboxSize",
                    "value": "1 GB"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "isPrimaryMailbox",
                    "value": "No"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `services` object. What you want to filter Dictionary.

Comment: You are always considering the first attribute, you have to refilter the $0.attributes to return isPrimaryMailbox and then check its value.

Comment: i can`t understand your question.

Comment: Is there a public api to fetch this json ?

Comment: @s3cretshadow right now I am using local json file.

Comment: @PradipPatel, thanks for the reply, I want to get the services info whose atrributes value (isPrimaryMailbox) is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let serviceWithPrimaryEmail = services.filter({$0.attributes.[1].value == "Yes"})
// I used the index 1 because as I see in you JSON data, the isPrimaryMailBox is always in the second row.
```

Also, your JSON is badly formatted. If you are gonna use an associated Array, then why do you have to separate the key and value to a different key-value pair?

The `attributes` can simply be:

```
"attributes":  {
  "mailboxSize":"1 GB",
  "isPrimaryMailbox":true
}
```

Using boolean instead of string "YES" or "NO"

So that when you filter, you simple say

```
let serviceWithPrimaryEmail = services.filter({$0.attributes["isPrimaryMailbox"]})
```

Or if you really prefer the string "YES" then:

```
let serviceWithPrimaryEmail = services.filter({$0.attributes["isPrimaryMailbox"] == "YES"})
```

Comment: It is as per the server response, I cant change it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the type of services object. But here is how you can get primary email service from your JSON:

```
typealias JSON = [String: Any]
let json = yourJSONDict as? JSON
let services = (((json["data"] as? JSON)?["cust"] as? JSON)?["serv"] as? JSON)?["services"] as? [JSON]
let primaryEmailService = services?.filter { service in
    if (service["type"] as? String) == "MAILBOX" {
        for attribute in service["attributes"] as? [[String: String]] ?? [] {
            if (attribute["name"] == "isPrimaryMailbox") && (attribute["value"] == "Yes") {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
    .first
```

**Edited:**

If you don't want to use for loop, you can use filter and reduce only:

```
let primaryEmailService = services?
    .filter {
        let attributes = $0["attributes"] as? [[String: String]] ?? []

        return ($0["type"] as? String) == "MAILBOX"
            && attributes.reduce(false, { $0 || (($1["name"] == "isPrimaryMailbox") && ($1["value"] == "Yes")) })
}
    .first
```

Please note, that worse case complexity for both approaches are equal. But best case complexity for the first approach is better, because you don't have to loop over all attributes in reduce function. And Swift compiler isn't smart enough for now to stop reduce looping after the first match (false || true always gives true. There is no need to proceed if we have one true).

Comment: I want to use a higher-order function like a filter, for loop is not a good idea.